# Interacting with an open application via web link

Tags: c#, web

This is likely a duplicate but I have no idea what this thing is called so I'm mostly coming here for a point in the right direction.

Sometimes we see these links on the internet for example for steam or opening torrents that look like this `steam://run/440` (grabbed from steam, this one runs TF2) or this for a magnet link `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:9da...`.

I was wondering how can I make a browser accept these links for my own application, and how can I make my application accept them and act accordingly?

My program is a C# WinForms daemon that runs in the background available in the system tray.

Like I said this is probably a duplicate and I don't mind if it gets marked as one, I just don't know what these things are even called and I would just like to be pointed in the right direction :).

Comment: You should register your own protocol in Windows Registry and handle opening your app with it as an argument. If your app is constantly up there will be some more to do with communication with already running instance.

Comment: @CyrilDurand yes I think that points me in the right direction, closing the question now, cheers!